# Typeerror: source is not iterable while uploading file into ipfs by using web3storage

Tags: web3js, js-ipfs, ipfs-http-client, ipfs-cli

[image]Yesterday I bought my new laptop and installed all the stuffs like react, web3.storage etc on new versions.

I have a copy of my same source code on my another computer. In my computer this code work fine but not in my new laptop [image]

I tried to upload my file on web3storage but not working.

Help me to recover !!

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem using nft.storage/web3.storage, i fixed it by removing `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and re-installing it again.

you can also try create-react-app again, i think it was a problem with webpack

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React and building apps with web3.storage, you might like the new React, etc components we are shipping as part of our beta w3up API. https://beta.ui.web3.storage